# T-Sql what's wrong with this

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm actually an ORACLE-guy. But I now I have to create a simple function in T-SQL (customer uses SQL-Srv 2008, no chance upgrading)

error message:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure create_view, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'view'.

so? what's wrong with this create view stmt?

```
create function create_view (@tab_name  varchar(64))
returns int
as
begin
    declare
        @error int
    ;
    begin
        create view [dbo].[target_list]
            as select * from @tab_name
        ;   
        set @error=@@ERROR
        return @error   
    end
end
```

thx in advance

Comment: A function cannot create a view. Only a stored procedure could, and even then it must use dynamic SQL (`EXEC`), since a `CREATE VIEW` must be the first statement in a batch. (And you *really* don't want to use `SELECT *` in a view if you can help it, because the view can break if the definition of the table changes.)

Comment: [`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql#interoperability) and [Create UDFs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine) documentation that may help.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, function is allow only SELECT statement. Function does not support DML and DDL statements. [Reference](http://www.sambhashanam.com/can-i-write-dml-statements-in-sql-server-functions/)

> DML Statments includes INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
>
> DDL Statement includes CREATE,DROP